# How do I create a query with mysql using data from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a working query that provides a list of property by price and date. What I am trying to do is only list properties that are a specific category type. The category types are listed in another table. Category types include homes, land and condos. stype = 1 is for listings for sale.

Working Query:

```
SELECT title as Description, price AS Price, date(modified) AS Updated FROM #__property WHERE stype = 1 ORDER BY price DESC
```

How to do I get this data to only list categories that are only land? The other data needs to be pulled from another table #__property_categories. 5 is the id for land.

```
FROM #___property_categories WHERE id=5
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the structure of your tables?

Comment: how do i know which rows from `#___iproperty_categories` apply to a particular `#__property` row?

Comment: What does the #___iproperty_categories table have in common with #__property?

Comment: #__iproperty_categories is suppose to be #__property_categories. #__property is the table of property listings and #__property_categories is the type. So I am trying to get a list of properties but only the ones that are land.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up how to do JOINS in mysql. I am not sure how your database is structured, but you can create references to rows in other tables. A join would look similar to the code below. If there is no reference in your database and you do not have write access to the database you may be out of luck.

```
SELECT 
p.title as Description, 
p.price AS Price, 
p.date(modified) AS Updated 
FROM #__property p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #_categories c ON c.ID = p.categoryID
WHERE c.stype = 1 
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```